# How do you set the ripple color of a material-ui ListItem?

Tags: material-ui

I can seem to find anywhere in the documentation how to go about setting the ripple color on a material-ui ListItem. I have the ListItem wrapped in a MuiThemeProvider with my overridden theme like this:

```
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    hoverColor: 'red',
  },
});

<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
  <ListItem>
    ...
  </ListItem>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

What palette color property should I set to change the ripple color?

Answer (score 13):

The ripple effect comes from a child component called TouchRipple. Specifically, the ripple color comes from the `background-color` of an element which is selectable using the `MuiTouchRipple-child` class. The ripple color is `currentColor` by default, but can be overridden easily.

Note that this works for any button-based component, not just ListItem.

## Examples:

#### [Styled Components API](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#styled-components-api):

```js
const MyListItem = styled(ListItem)`
    .MuiTouchRipple-child {
        background-color: red;
    }
`;
```

#### [Hook API](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#hook-api):

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        '.MuiTouchRipple-child': {
            backgroundColor: 'red';
        }
    }
});

const MyListItem = () {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <ListItem button className={classes.root}>Hook</ListItem>;
}
```

#### Global CSS:

```css
.MuiListItem-root .MuiTouchRipple-child {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: This is the best option if you don't wanna mess with TouchRippleProps property.

Answer (score 5):

This is how you can globally change ripple color to red.

```js
import React from "react";
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    // Style sheet name
    MuiTouchRipple: {
      // Name of the rule
      child: {
        // Some CSS
        backgroundColor: "red"
      }
    }
  }
});

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <List>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText primary="Item One" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText primary="Item Two" />
        </ListItem>
        {/* <ListItem button> ... </ListItem> */}
      </List>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[Play with the code in CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-change-global-ripple-color-4uy15?file=/App.js).

**Useful links:**

- Here's what [the theme object](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/) looks like with the default values.
- [The `overrides` key](https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/) enables you to customize the appearance of all instances of a component type.

Answer (score 4):

I got here working on a similar issue on the Button, but it appears to be consistent across ripple effect, so perhaps this will help someone in the future.

In Material-UI next/v1, the rippleColor is linked explicitly to the label color of the element. If you want the ripple and label to be different colors, you have to override the label color separately.

```
import MUIButton from 'material-ui/Button';
import {withStyles} from 'material-ui/styles';

const Button = (props) => {

    return <MUIButton className={props.classes.button}>Hat</MUIButton>

const styles = {
    button: {color: 'rebeccapurple'}
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Button);
```

This should get you an overridden ripple color.

Comment: If you don't want to change the button label color itself, you can just apply

Comment: If you don't want to change the button label color itself, you can just apply text color style to the ripple itself:

    `const styles = {
      buttonRipple: { color: "#f00" }
    };
    const MyButton = props => <Button TouchRippleProps={{
      classes: {
        root: props.classes.buttonRipple
      }
    }}>Click me</Button>
    export default withStyles(styles)(MyButton);`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the color of the ripple effect it can be done through the theme like you tried to do.

In the theme you can change the TouchRippleProps's classes and define your color in the CSS style you have.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider, Button } from '@material-ui/core';

const theme= createMuiTheme({
    props:{
        MuiButtonBase: {
            TouchRippleProps: {
                classes: {
                    root: 'CustomizeTouchRipple'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

export default function App() {

return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Button>Click</Button>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

And in the CSS style file:

```
.CustomizeTouchRipple {
  color: red;
}
```

Simple as that.

#### Update 1:

Instead of using a CSS class style you can directly put `style: {color: red[500]}`.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track! To change the ripple color, your theme should be:

```
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  ripple: {
    color: 'red',
  },
});
```

...however, that changes the ripple color for most of the `material-ui` components, not just ListItem. You can change the ripple color directly on the `ListItem` with the `focusRippleColor` and `touchRippleColor` properties:

```
<ListItem focusRippleColor="darkRed" touchRippleColor="red" primaryText="Hello" />
```

Comment: Is there any doc for `touchRippleColor`?

Comment: Not that I know of - it's what I'm trying to use now (with `ButtonBase`) - I think both of us will have to use the source code for that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like in the current version I need to use the `sx` prop on `<ListItem />`.

```tsx
<ListItem
  sx={(theme) => ({
    "& .MuiTouchRipple-child": {
      backgroundColor: `${theme.palette.primary.main} !important`,
    },
  })}
>
  Content
</ListItem>
```

Answer (score -2):

this worked for me:

```
.mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle,
.mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-ripple .mat-ripple-element,
.mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-ripple .mat-ripple-element:not(.mat-radio-persistent-ripple),
.mat-radio-button.mat-accent:active .mat-radio-persistent-ripple {
  background-color: mat-color($my-gray, 500);
}
```